# Can you switch the sides of operator+

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So basically I have a class "Sentence" that #includes "Word".

Sentence is a linked list of words

Here's my Question

"Word + Sentence returns a new Sentence with the Word added to the beginning"
so basically

```
Word w = "The";
Sentence s = "dog jumped high."
//the object type of w+s should be a sentence
```

However, I get the error,

```
'Sentence' does not name a type
//this is in reference to the return type of overloaded operator+ function, which is in the word class
```

So is there a way to flip the right hand and left hand sides of the operator+ overload so that I can put the code in the Sentence class.

I can't put the code in the Sentence class because there is a separate overload function where I need

```
s+w
```

to return a sentence with the word added to the end

Comment: The problem is that you can't declare a function returning `Sentence` until after you have defined the `Sentence` class. To avoid this problem, use non-member operator overloads (which is a good idea anyway). [See here for a full rundown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: Give sentence a non-explicit constructor which takes a word to create a 1 word sentence. Now you only need one non-member operator+ taking two sentences, and you can pass words to it too.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That is incorrect.  You can declare a function returning `Sentence` as long as `Sentence` is declared.  No definition for `Sentence` is required unless you are also defining the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, operators do not have to be members at all.  So just define the operator outside of your classes:

```
Sentence operator+(const Word &word, const Sentence &sentence);
```

Also note that you can forward declare classes:

```
class Sentence; // forward declaration

class Word {
    Sentence operator+(const Sentence &sentence) const;
};

class Sentence {
    ...
};

// Now that Sentence is defined (not just declared),
// you can define operator+ for Word (instead of just declaring it)
Sentence Word::operator+(const Sentence &sentence) const {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The whole operator+ approach is going to be slow, copying linked lists of strings millions of times. Let it go.

Comment: I should note that my classes are all separated by headers and implementation files.
So I tried both ways. The first way keeps giving me an error saying that the function is already defined in other places.
The other gives me an error saying how the the class Sentence is incomplete. I've been trying to solve there errors for a couple hours now.

Comment: @user3400223: That's not really enough to understand what is going on.  I suggest asking another question, with code snippets and error messages.